# 0 iowait on a io-intensive application. What my cpu spent time on?

Tags: mysql, linux, cpu

I did a test on my VM.
It's a simple while-true loop to insert data into MySQL installed on the same machine.

When the code is running, I noticed it make 50% CPU in us, and 50% id, 0 wa.

I think the bottle neck is disk IO. Looking forward to get a high `wa` in `top`. But the fact, I got 0 on `wa` and 50 `idle`.
I guess it's may because disk cache, but I don't know how to prove my idea.

I don't know why there's 50% idle and what to do to improve the performance.
Is there something I missed or can do further?

the output of `top`:

[image]

the output of `iotop`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While True loops can use up a lot of CPU. If that wouldn't completely destroy the functionality of your code, you could insert a pause into your loop so the loop does not use up all your CPU